# java unable to set size for textfield

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code for creating a frame with a text field:

```
   static  void showteacherDel()
    {
    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
    frame3.setSize(640,480);
    JPanel pn = new JPanel();
    pn.setSize(640,480);
    frame3.add(pn);
    frame3.setResizable(false);

    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setSize(300,500);
    Component add = pn.add(tf);

    //frame3.pack();
    frame3.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Now here is the problem. You see that I have  created a panel and then added my text field to it.

The reason for that was that my text field, no matter what size I set, spawned whole of the frame.

So I created a panel and added the text field to it.

But no matter what size I give, it shows a point object, which is actually a text field.

Comment: What is your "desired output"?

Comment: Are you trying to set the font size of the text in your JTextField?

Comment: @OhAuth iam actually trying to create a text feild...iam trying t set its size but it is not visible...by not visible i mean whatever size i set...it only shows a point object

Comment: @Sky'sOnUrHead Isn't that because your JTextField has no content? You need to use setText to give it some content.

Comment: @OhAuth thats right but that will make my text field dependent on some text pre inputted...what i want is to give it a deafault height and width... i have used setBounds but still it is not visible...just showing a point text field

Comment: The short answer is, don't.  Use an appropriate layout manager and sizing hints (like `setColumns`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is you don't seem to understand how components are laid out via the layout management API, for example, if we take a look at the code we can see:

```
JFrame frame3=new JFrame();
frame3.setSize(640,480);
JPanel pn=new JPanel();
// Pointless, as the JFrame is using a `BorderLayout`
// so the component will be the available size of it's parent
// container...
//pn.setSize(640,480);
frame3.add(pn);
frame3.setResizable(false);

JTextField tf=new JTextField();
// Pointless, as pn is using a `FlowLayout` so the
// text field will be laid out using it's preferred size
//tf.setSize(300,500);
// Provide a sizing hint, in combination with the fields
// font...
tf.setColumns(25);
Component add = pn.add(tf);

//frame3.pack();
frame3.setVisible(true);
```

I'm not sure why you would want a `JTextField` to `500` pixels high, maybe you want a `JTextArea` instead?

Take a closer look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
```

I have added 10 in bracket which will give it a size.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tf.setText(" Your Text ");

add That into your panel , then after that add that panel into your frame then setVisible(true) then it will definite visible

Comment: as i stated above..that will make my feild dependent on some text pre inputted...whereas i want a default height and width for it.. i dont know why is this happening i have done these things before too :(